# How to detect Keyboard key pressed in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to detect whenever the user presses any keyboard key.

Any method which is called only on typing any character and not when keyboard is shown.

Thanks!!

Comment: I have a question for you instead, how can the user type anything if the keyboard is not being shown?

Comment: Good answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216245/how-to-handle-key-events-in-iphone

Comment: Are u using textfield?

check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event

Comment: @OscarGomez If I recall correctly, this is possible when using a Bluetooth keyboard or a keyboard dock.

Comment: This would also be useful for page turning devices (Bluetooth HID keyboards).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can directly handle keyboard events every-time a user presses a key:

**Swift**

For Textfield use following delegate method -

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
```

}

For TextView use following delegate method -

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

}
```

**Objective C**

In case of **UITextField**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
          shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
          replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Do something here...
}
```

In Case of **UITextView** :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView
      shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
      replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    // Do something here...
}
```

So every-time one of these method is called for each key you press using keyboard.

You can use NSNotificationCenter also. You only need do add any of these in ViewDidLoad method.

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
```

**UITextField :**

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(textFieldText:)
                           name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                         object:yourtextfield];
```

Then you can put your code in method `textFieldText:`:

```
- (void)textFieldText:(id)notification {

    // Do something here...
}
```

**UITextView**

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                       selector:@selector(textViewText:)
                           name:UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                         object:yourtextView];
```

Then you can put your code in method `textViewText:`:

```
- (void)textViewText:(id)notification {

    // Do something here...
}
```

Hope it helps .

Comment: If I have a UITextView and I press the ReturnKey, the method textViewDidChange will also be called. Is there a way to recognize which key has been pressed on the keyboard?

Comment: What about for key presses in a UIWebView?

Comment: Note: shouldChangeTextInRange: doesn't get called if the text field is empty and you press the delete key. Text field seems to detect that the field hasn't changed so the delegate method doesn't need to be fired = /

Comment: what value is sent if the user presses the shift key?

Comment: There is no shift key in iPhone keyboard.

Comment: @NishantTyagi, I'm using the same event and handling tab key ('\t'). It works fine from the simulator using Hardware Keyboard, but it does not work with device using external blue tooth keyboard, even the delegate is not fired. Do I need to handle differently for external blue tooth keyboard?

Comment: But how should you handle shouldChangeTextInRange  boolians correctly so that if the user is actually typing or deleting the text, it would return Yes and if only the keyboard is up and theyre not typing it would return NO ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keyboard is showing as a result of the user tapping on a UITextfield, you can make yourself the delegate and implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

It will be called every time a user presses a key.

Comment: this will call everytime, but if user clear all the text, this will not called

Comment: If the textfield is empty and press back space button it doesn't called.