# text changed event in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.1

I have

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextView: UITextView
```

and I want that when there is a change inside the text then print to console: `blabla`.

I tried to add the following function, but when I change the text nothing happens:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    switch (textView) {
        case messageTextView: print("blabla")
        default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use textViewDidChange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529018/how-do-i-use-textviewdidchange)

Comment: @Kamran IMO, the question you linked is of worse quality than this one (no code provided in the one you linked), I'd recommend marking that question as a dupe of this one instead.

Comment: @jrh I linked that question to read the answer that has a fix for this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set the delegate inside `viewDidLoad`

```
textView.delegate = self
```

//

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextViewDelegate  {
```