# iOS : How to detect any key pressed when use a BT keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, key, pressed

I have to implement a manufacturer keyboard test app of iOS on iPad.

I am surveying on this topic right now.

According to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016729/how-to-detect-keyboard-key-pressed-in-iphone)

```
[_myUITextField becomeFirstResponder];
[_myUITextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
}

-(IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender{
    UITextField *_field = (UITextField *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%@",[_field text]);
}
```

With these code I can detect the letter(like 1,2,3,a,b,c...) I pressed in my app, but not all key pressed (like fn, ctl, cmd ...etc?)

Anyone know how to achieve this...thanks^^

Comment: BTW, I do not care if it's a public or private API be use.

Answer (score 0):

Try Notification center instead.

```
 NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
```

UITextField :

```
[notificationCenter addObserver:self
                   selector:@selector (textFieldText:)
                       name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                     object:yourtextfield];
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks first, but the result is the same as previous method, it can't detect any key as well.