# Virtual keyboard covers html element in Safari on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, height

1. Editable html element takes 100% of a screen's height.
2. On element focus a virtual keyboard comes up and covers partly element in
   Safari.

How to tell element by CSS/JavaScript to take 100% of visible height = 100vh - keyboard height ?

[image]

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023549/get-viewport-height-when-soft-keyboard-is-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023549/get-viewport-height-when-soft-keyboard-is-on) does this help?

Comment: Shame on me, the answer is really in your link. Last time I checked it was not there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023549/get-viewport-height-when-soft-keyboard-is-on) and as [Nathan Manousos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529891/nathan-manousos) commented

> window.visualViewport.height

can help to find the actual visible content height on a phone.

Thanks [GhostPengy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2941909/ghostpengy) for pointing.